# How can I update the DataGridView from a button in another form?

Tags: c#, methods, datagridview, get

I have a form containing DataGridView and I have another form that inserts the data into the database and I want to update the DataGridview from the last form
attached to you
My code is that it works sometimes and sometimes it does not update
The problem appears only if the DataGridView is empty

this code in form FRM_RECEIPTS

```
        private static FRM_RECEIPTS frm;

        static void frm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            frm = null;
        }
        public static FRM_RECEIPTS getMainForm
        {
            get
            {
                if (frm == null)
                {
                    frm = new FRM_RECEIPTS();
                    frm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(frm_FormClosed);

                }
                return frm;
            }
        }
```

This code is in button1 within FRM_RECEIPT

```
 FRM_RECEIPTS frm = new FRM_RECEIPTS();
 FRM_RECEIPTS.getMainForm.dgvRecipts.DataSource
 = receipt.SearchRecepits(frm.txtSearch.Text, frm.coBoxState.Text);
```

SearchRecepits method

```
public DataTable SearchRecepits(string criterion , string state)
        {
            DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
            DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
            SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[2];
            param[0] = new SqlParameter("@criterion", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            param[0].Value = criterion;

            param[1] = new SqlParameter("@state", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            param[1].Value = state;

            Dt = DAL.selectData("SearchRecepits", param);
            DAL.Close();
            return Dt;
        }
```

Comment: Can you please show the SearchRecepits() method?

Comment: I update Question

Comment: Put this line in button1 before assigning a Datasource to DataGridView
 `FRM_RECEIPTS.getMainForm.dgvRecipts.DataSource = null;`

Comment: please accept my answer posted below

Comment: The problem has not been resolved !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first set datasource to null and then assign a datasource to make DataGridView Consistent.

Add this line to button1 before assigning a Datasource to DataGridView

```
FRM_RECEIPTS.getMainForm.dgvRecipts.DataSource = null;
```

So button1 will look like

```
 FRM_RECEIPTS frm = new FRM_RECEIPTS();
 FRM_RECEIPTS.getMainForm.dgvRecipts.DataSource = null;
 FRM_RECEIPTS.getMainForm.dgvRecipts.DataSource = receipt.SearchRecepits(frm.txtSearch.Text, frm.coBoxState.Text);
```

Comment: Can you specify the test cases when you face the problem